# How do I find out the conflicting path?

Tags: android, adb

I'm testing an app for Android and ADB is complaining about different versions. I get error `adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing...` From other topics I've learned that most likely two different paths are here to blame. I ran `adb version` and got one path but I don't know how to find out the conflicting path so I can shoot it from orbit. I checked out
`.bashrc` file and found only one environmental variable concerning Android development

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/`

What should I try ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting locally most likely one `adb` version is running by your Android Studio and second one by you from command line.
To find all `adb` executables:

```
sudo find / -name adb -type f -perm /u=x -exec ls -la {} \;
```

To find where the cli `adb` is linked, run:

`` WHICH_ADB=`which adb`; ls -la $WHICH_ADB ``

To find curently running adb:

```
sudo ps -ef | grep [a]db
```

output:

```
lojza  3542     1  0 15:22 ?        00:00:00 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
```

To check where this one is located use its pid - `3542` in this case:

```
sudo ls -la /proc/3542/exe
```